# Custom cell template for angular-calendar-week-view

Tags: angular-calendar, angularjs-ng-template

Can you please let me know if there any way to customize the cell template in week view?
Currently I'm using something like:

```
<mwl-calendar-week-view
          *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Week"
          [viewDate]="viewDate"
          [events]="events"
          [refresh]="refresh"
          (eventClicked)="dayEventClicked($event.event)"
          (eventTimesChanged)="eventTimesChanged($event)"
          [eventTemplate]="customCellTemplateWeekly">
        </mwl-calendar-week-view>
        <ng-template #customCellTemplateWeekly  let-day="day" let-locale="locale">
---------
</ng-template>
```

But I'm not getting the events inside the ng-template so that I can render it accordingly.
Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You used [eventTemplate] and as far as i have worked on this, the only thing that was accessible is let-weekEvent="weekEvent" where weekEvent.event is the one you want. there is no property that  gives all events for a day in this afaik, Please correct me if i am wrong.